# MyEclipse 2017 CI 10 error on Maven Projects

Tags: java, spring, maven, myeclipse

i have imported a **maven** project to *MyEclipse 2017* and when i want do an update with my local maven repository i get this error

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.navigator 4 2 2018-03-19 23:07:47.288
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.navigator".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/m2e/jdt/internal/MavenClasspathContainerSaveHelper
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.getSavedContainer(BuildPathManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.initialize(MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2939)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1970)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:3424)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2693)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2857)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1962)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.determineIfOnClasspath(JavaModelManager.java:1107)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.create(JavaModelManager.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.create(JavaModelManager.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.create(JavaCore.java:3303)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.JavaNavigatorContentProvider.convertToJavaElements(JavaNavigatorContentProvider.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.JavaNavigatorContentProvider.interceptUpdate(JavaNavigatorContentProvider.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.extensions.SafeDelegateTreeContentProvider.interceptUpdate(SafeDelegateTreeContentProvider.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorPipelineService$4.run(NavigatorPipelineService.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorPipelineService.pipelineInterceptUpdate(NavigatorPipelineService.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorPipelineService.interceptUpdate(NavigatorPipelineService.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.update(CommonViewer.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.update(StructuredViewer.java:2038)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleLabelProviderChanged(StructuredViewer.java:1209)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleLabelProviderChanged(CommonViewer.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer$1.labelProviderChanged(ContentViewer.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider$1.run(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.fireLabelProviderChanged(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.labelProviderChanged(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.ProblemsLabelDecorator.fireProblemsChanged(ProblemsLabelDecorator.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.ProblemsLabelDecorator.access$0(ProblemsLabelDecorator.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.ProblemsLabelDecorator$1.problemsChanged(ProblemsLabelDecorator.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.ProblemMarkerManager$1.run(ProblemMarkerManager.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4203)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3819)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.block(ModalContext.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.run(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.internalPerformFinish(RefactoringWizard.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.UserInputWizardPage.performFinish(UserInputWizardPage.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.resource.DeleteResourcesWizard$DeleteResourcesRefactoringConfigurationPage.performFinish(DeleteResourcesWizard.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.performFinish(RefactoringWizard.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.okPressed(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3816)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation$1.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.actions.DeleteResourcesHandler.execute(DeleteResourcesHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommandInContext(LegacyHandlerService.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.LTKLauncher.runCommand(LTKLauncher.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.LTKLauncher.openDeleteWizard(LTKLauncher.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.DeleteResourceAction.run(DeleteResourceAction.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.reorg.DeleteAction.run(DeleteAction.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3816)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very odd, given that the class that can't be found is in the same jar as the BuildPathManager class which is calling a method in the problem class. This implies some corruption somewhere. First of all, take a look at the `org.eclipse.m2e.jdt_1.7.0.me201611191457.jar`, which will be in the `plugins` folder of the MyEclipse installation. You can look at the jar with any archive program (e.g. winzip or winrar); check the `org/eclipse/m2e/jdt/internal` folder within the jar file, it should contain the class that wasn't found. If it isn't there, then I suggest a re-install of the latest release of MyEclipse. If it is there, there might be some caching problem, so start MyEclipse with the -clean option from the command line to see if that helps (in a terminal/command window go to the installation folder and enter the command `myeclipse -clean`).

If you try the latter option but still have no success, try a fresh workspace and/or reinstall MyEclipse anyway.